# Windows 10 pro task manager show Very High on power usage on unity editor, How can I Fix it?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

The [Unity editor](https://unity3d.com/unity/editor) was not responding; I had to shut it down the `edn` task from the task manager. How may I troubleshoot why it consumes so much power and why it went unresponsive?

[Very high power usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D66r3.jpg)

And

[Very high power usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIzcz.jpg)

Comment: Unity is using 20% of your processor.  This new behavior?

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is that I had a opened project of the unity and once I clicked play to run the game in the unity editor the unity editor freezed not reposnding and the power usage went to very high. Until I clicked play it was fine once clicked on play in the editor it happened. The unity freezed and the useage of power went to very high.

Comment: @Ramhound I know unity take a lot of resources but why it was not responding once the power usage went very high ?

Comment: Because your CPU handles responding to ending a task?  So if your system is busy and all the resources are given to Unity then you run into this problem

Comment: @Ramhound And how can I solve it or what should I do so it will not happen next time ? My pc system is windows 10 pro nvidia geforce gtx 770 and 6GB ram. And nothing else was working in the background on the unity.